# How to prevent my MPMoviePlayerController from getting black when back from a webView containing a YouTube Video - iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, video, uinavigationcontroller, mpmovieplayercontroller

Here is the context :
NavigationController -> FirstViewController -> SecondViewController

FirstViewController display a MPMoviePlayerController in embedded mode, and buttons to go to SecondViewController. This MPMoviePlayerController is reading a local .m4v file.

SecondViewController display a UIWebView with web pages containing YouTube videos.

Here are the steps :

1. the user read the video on FirstViewController (works fine)
2. the user press one of the buttons to go to SecondViewController
3. the user press one of the youtube video, that will play in embedded mode in the webView (works fine too)
4. the user press the Back button in NavigationItem

The problem appear at this particular moment :

**When the user come back from SecondViewController, the MPMoviePlayerController is black.**

I tried using prepareToPlay on the moviePlayer in viewWillAppear and/or viewDidAppear. In both cases, I got a good result for half a sec and then the MoviePlayer view is turned to black again.
I think that when the viewDidUnload is called in the SecondViewController, something happen that put a brief access to the web embbedded MoviePlayer.

Any idea about how to solve the problem ?

**Note :** this only appear on a device because videos don't appear on UIWebView in simulator. I tried to reproduce it with another MPMoviePlayerController in the second view but putting a prepareToPlay in the viewDidAppear solved it...

**Note 2:** this problem only appear on iPad. I tried to reproduce it on iPhone but the youtube player won't play video in embedded mode on iPhone...

Comment: YouTube within a web view does NOT use MPMoviePlayerController - it just looks similar.

Comment: Ok I'll correct it in the question, but as I say, the problem appear only when the user play the video in the WebView (which is embedded in the web page in iPad).
Any idea to resolve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

There should be no movie player code. Just put your video url on your web view code it shall work fine.

Comment: That is not answering my question, I edited it to be more precise. Thanks for your interest anyway

Comment: I am not getting why MPMoviePlayerController??without it youtube link shall work fine on web view.

Comment: A I say in my question, the Youtube vdeo is in the webview whereas the MPMovieController is reading a local m4v file. I updated the question again to help comprehension